How can I store additional information in a BLE device/Beacon
I have a requirement where I'm building an app for iOS and Android (currently in React Native) where I want to look for BLE devices in the background and based on the BLE Beacon encounter I'll call some APIs in the background.
Right now, my solution is more iOS-focused because I know if I get it working for iOS, Android will not be much of a problem.
For background scanning in the iOS, I need to specify the UUIDs (Going to keep UUIDs same accross all BLE devices) in the app so it knows what to look for.
Now the problem is I need to uniquely iddentify each beacon so I know where the user is. The corrosponding information for that beacon would be in our database (location, name of place, etc). I can not find an approporiate way to store such unique IDs in my beacon that I can get without a connection. I know there is some bits available to store custom information in advertising channel but I'm unable to find a practical example for it.
Someone suggested to store such infomration in the device name but I think it's not reliable and anyone can change it.
My questions would be is it actually possible to store such custom information?
If yes, then how can I do that so it stays there even if I reset the device.

Use iBeacon. It allows you to specify two 16 bit numbers along with the uuid. You use these two numbers to look up the required information from your database.

Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy_beacon, there are a number of Beacon protocols described there.

Thank you @Paulw11 is it something easily configurable by owners? As we will hand over these beacons to businesses, we don't want them to temper this information.

It depends on the beacon hardware you chose, but typically there is a PIN code to protect configuration.

"Now the problem is I need to uniquely iddentify each beacon so I know where the user is. " Isn't that why Major/Minor are? Like Major is a "facility", and "minor" is a room (or any more complex  combination according to your needs)?
